# Check if a variable is a specific string other wise do that

Tags: php

To check if a field has or not a string i simply do:

```
if( $mindmap !== 'hello' ) {...
```

That is fine however the field has a "*special*" string, exactly the following:

```
$mindmap = "{&quot;id&quot;:1}";
```

I tried:

```
if( $mindmap !== '{""};' ) {...
```

and

```
 if( $mindmap !== '{&quot;id&quot;:1}' ) {...
```

But that doesn't work and I don't know why to be honest, any idea?

Comment: see preg_match and regular expression, try using google

Comment: a more elaborated answer rather than sending to search for a solution would be better for me and for any future users if you don't mind

Comment: No comparison will work fine unless you strictly define *special* for this comparison. Once that is done its easy to bring both to the same level before comparison

Comment: For example if *special* characters can only be  html entities  you can decode them before comparing with a normal string

Comment: @HankyPanky thanks, could you elaborate it more into an answer based on the code in the question please?

Comment: Sure but only you can tell us what are the possible special characters in this case. Only then an answer can be useful otherwise it will be a fluke which works in only the given case and nothing else

Comment: no more than the specific ones wrote above, no other types @HankyPanky

Comment: @webDev why argue for a simple help question?

Comment: heheh this is not argue, i am just making you clear about my comment and your comment back. chill out bud. see my comment and yours and decide whether thats is argue or not hehehehe

Comment: @webDev boy you do realise I came here with a simple help question and you simply sent me to rtm? That ain't love

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Based on our discussion in comments it looks like that the input string sometimes has html entities in it. Here is a proof of concept that you can build upon, it decodes any possible entities within the string before comparing it with a standard one.

```
<?php

$mindmap = "{&quot;id&quot;:1}";
var_dump( $mindmap === '{"id":1}');                         //false
var_dump( html_entity_decode($mindmap) === '{"id":1}');     //true
```

[Fiddle](https://eval.in/779459)

Your `if` would look like

```
if( html_entity_decode($mindmap) !== '{"id":1}')
```

Comment: thanks man, i was actually reading about html_entity_decode http://php.net/manual/en/function.html-entity-decode.php will try it now

Comment: ok great, that works. Used `if( html_entity_decode($mindmap) !== '{"id":1}') {  ?>` if you could add this will make the answer complete and I will accept it, thanks a lot

Answer (score 0):

```
$mindmap = "{&quot;id&quot;:1}";

echo "<pre>";
var_dump($mindmap !== "{&quot;id&quot;:1}"); exit; //bool(false)
var_dump($mindmap === "{&quot;id&quot;:1}"); exit; //bool(true)
```

Works perfectly...

what you need from that????

Comment: yeah with print_r not with echo tho

Comment: Nope, why i need that

Comment: @because you will realise it isn't decoded and that ain't going to output `{&quot;id&quot;:1}`